# mysql timestamp doesn't show Days

Tags: mysql, database, date

I'm using Date_format() but for some reason it doesn't show me the days, it just shows me the hours. For example if the hours are 51:01 it just shows me 03:00 (48+3) and if the hours are 24:02 it just shows me 12:02.

Anyone got an idea on what i should use? I'm counting the max hours of workers in 2016 and 2017.

Here is my code:

```
select Year(Date) AS Year,WorkerID, 
       Date_format(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(goes)-time_to_sec(comes))), '%h:%i') as H 
FROM Info 
Group by Year, WorkerID
```

Comment: That is how `%h` works.  If you want days, use `%d`.

Comment: Then i get 7th, 12:02 :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use decimal hours:

```
select Year(Date) AS Year, WorkerID, 
       (sum(time_to_sec(goes) - time_to_sec(comes))) / 3600 as decimal_hours 
from Info 
Group by Year, WorkerID;
```

You can use `concat to get this into HH:MM format, if you really want:

```
select Year(Date) AS Year, WorkerID, 
       concat_ws(':',
                 floor( (sum(time_to_sec(goes) - time_to_sec(comes))) / 3600),
                 lpad(floor(sum(time_to_sec(goes) - time_to_sec(comes))) / 60) % 60, 2, '0')
                 )
from Info 
Group by Year, WorkerID;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i get an error with "lpad", incorrect parameter count

Comment: and decimal hours get me "0,0169"